# How to make checkbox for is_private field as enum "Y/N"?

Tags: laravel-livewire, alpine.js

In  Laravel8/livewire/aplinejs I have field is_private as enum "Y/N".
I try to set checkbox with init value :

```
  <x-jet-checkbox id="hostel_room_is_private" type="checkbox" wire:model="form.is_private" @if 
  ($form['is_private'] == "Y") checked="checked" @endif value="Y"/>
```

but it does not work for me. Also how will I use it saving data?

How can it be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Step1: Add this in your livewire component.**

```
public $form['is_private']  = 'Y';
```

**Step2:**
Change your blade file like given below.

```
  <x-jet-checkbox id="hostel_room_is_private" type="checkbox" wire:model="form.is_private" />
```

Comment: No, this way does not work properly

Comment: What is the error showing ??

Comment: In this case checkbox is always checked, looks like "Y/N" - rendered as TRUE, but empty value as false